# Golang: Having trouble with nested JSON Unmarshaler

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

Given the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
)

type Somefin string

func (s *Somefin) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    log.Println("Unmarshaling",string(b))
    *s = Somefin("~"+string(b)+"~")
    return nil
}

type Wat struct {
    A, B string
    *Somefin
}

func main() {
    b := []byte(`{"A":"foo","B":"bar","Somefin":"baz"}`)
    w := &Wat{Somefin: new(Somefin)}

    err := json.Unmarshal(b,w)
    log.Println(w, err)
}
```

I get the following output:

```
# go run wat.go
2013/12/14 13:59:17 Unmarshaling {"A":"foo","B":"bar","Somefin":"baz"}
2013/12/14 13:59:17 &{  <nil>} <nil>
```

So the `Somefin` key is for some reason trying to Unmarshal the entire structure instead of just the key it ought to. Am I doing this wrong or is this a bug in the json encoder? This is on go 1.2, btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Why you are getting no result at the end

This is no bug in the decoder, it is a bug in your code. You're just assigning another address
to the local pointer `s` in `UnmarshalJSON`. Corrected code:

```
func (s *Somefin) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    log.Println("Unmarshaling",string(b))
    sn := Somefin("~"+string(b)+"~")
    *s = sn
    return nil
}
```

Semantics of `s = &sn`: Assign the address `&sn` to `s`. This is similar to `s = 42`.

Semantics of `*s = sn`: Copy whatever is `sn` to the place where `s` points to.

One requirement for this to work is that `s` points to a valid memory location and must not be `nil`.
Example usage of your code ([play](http://play.golang.org/p/4c-jaUEW79)):

```
w := &Wat{Somefin: new(Somefin)}

err := json.Unmarshal(b,w)
log.Printf("%#v (%s)\n", w, err)
```

Crucial is the initialization of `Wat` with a new `Somefin` so that the pointer `s` in 
`UnmarshalJSON` is valid (points to the object created with `new(Somefin)`).

#### Why you are getting the whole string in `UnmarshalJSON`

Embedding is not polymorphism. While the method set of the embedded object (in your case
`Somefin`) is promoted to the outside, this does *not* mean that the method is now working
on the embedding struct rather than the embedded one.

Small example ([play](http://play.golang.org/p/JXyIQ0DMHv)):

```
type Inner struct { a int }
func (i *Inner) A() int { return i.a }

type Outer struct {
    *Inner
    a int
}

i := &Inner{}
o := Outer{Inner: i}

fmt.Println("Inner.A():", i.A())
fmt.Println("Outer.A():", o.A())

o.a = 2

fmt.Println("Outer.A():", o.A())
```

With polymorphism you would expect `Outer.A()` to return `2` as method `A()` would operate in
the scope of `Outer` and not `Inner` anymore. With embedding the scope is never changed and
`A()` will always remain operating on `Inner`.

The same effect prevents your `UnmarshalJSON` from seeing the two members `A` and `B` as these
are simply not in the scope of `Somefin`:

1. JSON library sees `UnmarshalJSON` on `Wat` because `UnmarshalJSON` from `Somefin` gets promoted to the outside
2. JSON library cannot find any matching element in `Somefin` and delivers the whole input

Comment: Thanks! You're right, my pointers were bad. I'll fix that in my example code in the OP. But the full string is still getting passed into the `UnmarshalJSON` method when it should be just `"baz"` (at least, I think....).

Comment: @MediocreGopher Sorry for being late, I had work to do. Although you've already found your answer I edited mine.

Comment: Thanks for that extra explanation, I really appreciate the extra clarity :)

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out.

If you have the struct definition like this:

```
type Wat struct {
    A, B string
    Somefin
}
```

Then the error I described in the OP happens. But if you do:

```
type Wat struct {
    A, B string
    Somefin Somefin
}
```

Then it doesn't. Check out Chris's comment to this answer for a good explanation of why.

Comment: It is not a bug in the json library, but rather an odd interaction with struct embedding. The embedded struct's UnmarshalJSON method gets promoted to the containing struct. The result is that the json library sees that method on the Wat struct and calls it for the whole struct instead of just the nested Somefin. Read down this section of the language spec for more info: http://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types

Comment: Oh ok, neat! I'll change my answer to reflect that. Thanks!