# json.Unmarshal fails when embedded type has UnmarshalJSON

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I'm trying to unmarshal a struct that has an embedded type. When the embedded type has an UnmarshalJSON method, the unmarshaling of the outer type fails:

https://play.golang.org/p/Y_Tt5O8A1Q

```
package main


import (
    "fmt"

    "encoding/json"
)

type Foo struct {
    EmbeddedStruct
    Field string
}

func (d *Foo) UnmarshalJSON(from []byte) error {
    fmt.Printf("Foo.UnmarshalJSON\n")

    type Alias Foo
    alias := &Alias{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(from, alias); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Error in Foo.UnmarshalJSON: json.Unmarshal returned an error:\n%v\n", err)
    }
    *d = Foo(*alias)

    return nil
}

type EmbeddedStruct struct {
    EmbeddedField string
}

func (d *EmbeddedStruct) UnmarshalJSON(from []byte) error {
    fmt.Printf("EmbeddedStruct.UnmarshalJSON\n")

    type Alias EmbeddedStruct
    alias := &Alias{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(from, alias); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Error in EmbeddedStruct.UnmarshalJSON: json.Unmarshal returned an error:\n%v\n", err)
    }
    *d = EmbeddedStruct(*alias)

    return nil
}

func main() {

    data := `{"EmbeddedField":"embeddedValue", "Field": "value"}`
    foo := &Foo{}

    json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), foo)

    fmt.Printf("Foo: %v\n", foo)

    if foo.EmbeddedField != "embeddedValue" {
        fmt.Printf("Unmarshal didn't work, EmbeddedField value is %v. Should be 'embeddedValue'\n", foo.EmbeddedField)
    }

    if foo.Field != "value" {
        fmt.Printf("Unmarshal didn't work, Field value is %v. Should be 'value'\n", foo.Field)
    }

}
```

The output is:

```
Foo.UnmarshalJSON
EmbeddedStruct.UnmarshalJSON
Foo: &{{embeddedValue} }
Unmarshal didn't work, Field value is . Should be 'value'
```

... so both custom unmarshal functions ran. The value from the embedded struct is correct, but the value from the outer struct is lost.

If we simply remove the EmbeddedStruct.UnmarshalJSON method, it works as expected.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this expected? Or a bug? I'm sure there's a way I can tweak my UnmarshalJSON methods to get it working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is expected.

When you create the alias:

```
type Alias Foo
```

`Alias` will not inherit the methods of `Foo` since it is a different type with a different method set, which is what you wanted to achieve to avoid an infinite recursion.

*However*, the embedded `EmbeddedStruct`'s `UnmarshalJSON` method will instead be promoted!

So, `Alias` will have an `UnmarshalJSON` method that will only unmarshal `EmbeddedStruct`'s value, instead of using the default unmarshalling that you desired.

Comment: @DavidBrophy I am still trying to figure out how you can actually work around the problem. I will edit the answer if I figure it out. But, you are welcome :)

Comment: Yeah same here! I actually just found a duplicate question that doesn't come to any conclusion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20587157/golang-having-trouble-with-nested-json-unmarshaler

Comment: I worked around it by making a copy of the whole encoding/json package, and adding a new function "UnmarshalWithoutCustomUnmarshalers". Its not ideal, but it worked perfectly... I'll push the code to github at some point.