# Unmarshal embedded field pointer panics when field implements UnmarshalJSON

Tags: go

I have a `struct` that embeds an embedded pointer to another `struct`. When I use the default `json.Unmarshal` behavior, it works perfectly. But when I implement `UnmarshalJSON` for the ***embedded*** `struct`'s type but *not* the outer `struct`, then go panics with null pointer dereference.

If I implement `UnmarshalJSON` for the outer `struct` type as well, then it works. However, the outer struct has many fields that I would rather not have to manually unmarshal.

1. Why does implementing `UnmarshalJSON` on one and not the other cause a panic?
2. Is there a way to get it work without implemented `UnmarshalJSON` for the outer type?
3. If not, is there a simpler/less manual way to implement `UnmarshalJSON` for the outer type?

***Note:*** *There is a question with a similar title, "[json.Unmarshal fails when embedded type has UnmarshalJSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29667379/json-unmarshal-fails-when-embedded-type-has-unmarshaljson)
", but the issue there is different from mine.*

tl;dr: The rest of this question is just a lengthy example of the above.

#### Base Example

(play.golang.org [version](https://play.golang.org/p/yyFX-t8VMn9) of example)

The two structs, one with an embedded field pointer to the other:

*(Simplified for example -- this doesn't really need its own `UnmarshalJSON` but it demonstrates the problem.)*

```
type Obj struct {
    X int `json:"x"`
}

type Container struct {
    *Obj
    Y int `json:"y"`
}
```

Invoking unmarshal:

```
func main() {
    b := []byte(`{"x": 5, "y": 3}`)
    c := &Container{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(b, c)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error ummarshalling json: %+v\n", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("unmarshalled: %+v --> %+v\n", c, c.Obj)
}
```

Without implementing any `UnmarshalJSON` funcs, this works fine:

```
unmarshalled: &{Obj:0x416080 Y:3} --> &{X:5}
```

#### Panic

But, if I add `UnmarshalJSON` to the embedded `Obj` type only, then the program panics, as the `json.Unmarshal` call passes a `nil` pointer when it tries to unmarshal `*Obj`.

```
func (o *Obj) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) (err error) {
    m := make(map[string]int)
    err = json.Unmarshal(b, &m)
    if err != nil {
        return nil
    }
    o.X = m["x"] // the line indicated by panic
    return nil
}
```

Output:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[...]
main.(*Obj).UnmarshalJSON(0x0, 0x416030, 0x10, 0x10, 0x0, 0x0)
    /tmp/sandbox185809294/main.go:18 +0x130
[...]
```

**Question:** Why does it panic here but not with the default unmarshal behavior? I'd think that if a `nil` `*Obj` is being passed here, then the default behavior also passes around a `nil` pointer...

#### Fixing the panic

It no longer panics when I implement `UnmarshalJSON` for the outer `Container` type:

```
func (c *Container) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) (err error) {
    m := make(map[string]int)
    err = json.Unmarshal(b, &m)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    c.Obj = &Obj{X: m["x"]}
    c.Y = m["y"]
    return nil
}
```

But unmarshalling `Container` manually this way gets tedious if both the real `Container` and real `Obj` have more fields than this, each with different types.

**Question:** Is there a simpler way to prevent this panic?

Answer (score 1):

Because the default behavior checks for `nil` and your custom unmarshaller does not. You need some logic in your `UnmarshalJSON` to check if `o` is `nil` and behave appropriately, instead of assuming `o` is not `nil` (by trying to access one of its fields), thereby triggering a panic.

```
func (o *Obj) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) (err error) {
    if o == nil {
        return nil // maybe? What do you want to happen in this case?
    }
    m := make(map[string]int)
    err = json.Unmarshal(b, &m)
    if err != nil {
        return nil
    }
    o.X = m["x"] // the line indicated by panic
    return nil
}
```

Also just for future reference, your `*Obj` field is not an "anonymous field", it is an *embedded* field: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types

Comment: (thanks for correction about embedded field). Your solution's behavior is different from the behavior of the default unmarshal. your solution: `unmarshalled: &{Obj:<nil> Y:0} --> <nil>`; default: `unmarshalled: &{Obj:0x416080 Y:3} --> &{X:5}`. But because it *is* `nil`, I can't just set its value to a new `Obj{}` in the custom `UnmarshalJSON`.

Comment: I also didn't think `UnmarshalJSON` funcs needed to do their own `nil` checks. Doesn't `json.Unmarshal` handle that for them? From the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) for `json.Unmarshal`: "If v is nil or not a pointer, Unmarshal returns an InvalidUnmarshalError [...]" and then "To unmarshal JSON into a value implementing the Unmarshaler interface, Unmarshal calls that value's UnmarshalJSON method, including when the input is a JSON null"

Comment: @xgord The embedded field's (`*Obj`) methods get promoted and become part of the method set of the embedding type (`Container`). So json.Unmarshal checks whether Container is nil or not, later it checks if Container implements the json.Unmarshaler interface and that check returns true thanks to the embedded `*Obj` and its promoted methods, so json.Unmarshal calls UnmarshalJSON on the `(*Obj)(nil)` *through* the non-nil Container.

Comment: @mkopriva ohhhh, that makes sense. and indeed, if I initialize the `Container` obj as `c := &Container{Obj: &Obj{}}`, then the panic doesn't happen. I guess my problem was more similar to the part of the question I linked than I thought... thanks!

Comment: @xgord no problem, btw if you want to lazily initialize Obj you don't have to use a map inside Container's UnmarshalJSON, you could do something like: https://play.golang.com/p/80NH8ULZn7f

Comment: @mkopriva why doesn't that solution run into the same problem, where  `*Obj.UnmarshalJSON`  is promoted to become `temporary`'s `UnmarshalJSON`? (I tested it out, so I know it works -- I'm just confused why it's different than the original)

Comment: @xgord at the top i'm checking whether Obj is nil or not and if yes then I initialize it, so json.Unmarshal is safe to call UnmarshalJSON on it.

Comment: @xgord `(*temporary)(c)` converts the `c` value's type from `*Container` to `*temporary` but its contents don't change, its Obj is still initialized thanks to the `c.Obj = new(Obj)` line.

Comment: @mkopriva, that hack with a throwaway type is neat; thanks!

Comment: @mkopriva yes very handy! thanks for additional explanations. worthy of an official answer if you want to compile it all into one.